# Attempt to read property \"id\" on null

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make a post and every time I get the error'Attempt to read property "id" on null'...attached is the code for the project in question
this is the controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\post;

class postController extends Controller
{
  
    //create a post
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $attrs = $request->validate([
            'body' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $post = post::create([
            'body' => $attrs['body'],
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        ]);


        return response([
            'message' => 'post created',
            'post' => $post
        ], 200);

    }
```

Comment: `auth()->user()` is returning `null` and `null->id` is not valid... Are you signed in?

Comment: yeah am already signed in

Comment: Then something is wrong with your configuration, and you need to debug your local PHP code. The error is saying that you're not logged in, but if you think you are, _you_ need to figure out why. There isn't much we can help you with the posted code...

Comment: i wanted to provide the entire code from the model,controller,route and table but unfortunately stackoverflows says thats too much code which needs more explanation and when i give more explanation its still showing the error issue

Comment: is signin in same as logging in coz i Just registered /signup but didnt do anything else from that could that be the issue

Comment: Yes, signing in is the same as logging in. In order to use `auth()->user()` and not have it return `null`, you need to have logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Check the user is authenticated or not and also check in database id is auto increment or not .

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   
    if (auth()->check()) {
        $attrs = $request->validate([
            'body' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $post = post::create([
            'body' => $attrs['body'],
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        ]);

        return response([
            'message' => 'post created',
            'post' => $post
        ], 200);
    } else {
        return response(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
}
```

Comment: lemme try and check ...thanks for the help

Comment: This'll work, but you shouldn't need to use `auth()->check()` directly in a Controller like this. If you configure your Routes properly to only allow Authenticated Users to access specific Controller actions, the `auth()->check()` check will be performed _long_ before this code is hit.

Comment: Yes you can write code in middleware for authentication and write route inside middleware route group